# using autocomplete in app with ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, ransack

Good day. 
I hame a controller that uses ransack to find articles by their title.
I need  field that's used for finding info  to use autocomplete.
Currently it finds alright, but no autocomplete, could you assist me in that problem
and gem https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete-app?

Gemfile

```
 gem "ransack"
    gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'
    gem 'nifty-generators'
    gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.0'
```

in view:

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
  <%= f.label t('.find') %>
  <%= f.autocomplete_field :title_cont,
    articles_autocomplete_article_title_path, :size => 15 %><br />
  <%= f.submit :value=>'Search', :class=>'fl_right' %>
<% end %>
```

head of layout:

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag '/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js',
      '/javascripts/autocomplete-rails.js', '/javascripts/rails.js'  %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag '/stylesheets/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css' %>
```

controller

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :article, :title
```

**UPDATE 1**
and routes.rb

```
get 'articles/autocomplete_article_title'
```

**UPDATE 2**
in view , in place of  `<%= f.autocomplete_field :title_cont,`
used 
1 ) :title_start no changes
2) :articles_article_title_start and so on lead to errors.

**UPDATE 3**
i've edited routes.rb. moved   get 'articles/autocomplete_article_title' into scope of locale variable, **now it kind of works.**.. autocomplete drop down list appears... but empty :( have to fix that one now.

**UPDATE 4**
tried to use http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association. but it's for older version of rails... and so on

**UPDATE 5**
changed in routes.rb

```
  resources :articles do
    get 'autocomplete_article_title'
  end
```

No luck yet.

**UPDATE 6**
As far as i understand current problem is: ransack & autocomplete use one field.
It's suitable for ransack  that field of autocomplete_field  type. but i don't know how to make field name acceptable by ransack work with autocomplete. Could you help?

**UPDATE 7**
so in view

```
   f.text_field :title_start,
      "data-autocomplete" => articles_autocomplete_article_title_path,
      :size => 15
```

in routes.rb

```
scope '(:locale)' do
  resources :users
  resources :news
  resources :articles do

  end
  get 'articles/autocomplete_article_title'
  get "news/index" , as: 'news'

# match "/news*tail" => 'news#index'
  root :to => 'News#index', as: 'news'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
f.autocomplete_field :title_cont,
    articles_autocomplete_article_title_path, :size => 15
```

Try

```
f.text_field :title_cont, "data-autocomplete" => articles_autocomplete_article_title_path
```

In my project i used meta_search and simple_form and it was like

```
f.input :country_name_equals, url: autocomplete_country_name_path, :as => :autocomplete
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll do that. the problem with meta_search is that it's not for rails 3.... the author suggests using this gem for rails 3 app

Comment: I followed what's written here:
"The successor to MetaSearch is Ransack. It’s got features that MetaSearch doesn’t, along with some API changes. I haven’t had the time to dedicate to making it bulletproof yet, so I’m releasing a 1.1.x branch of MetaSearch to help with migrations to Rails 3.1.

This is intended to be a stopgap measure.

t’s important to note that the long-term migration path for your apps should be toward Ransack, which is written in a more sane manner that will make supporting new versions of Rails much easier going forward." https://github.com/ernie/meta_search

Comment: Did update 7... still no luck.
see what happens by yourself http://whispering-eyrie-8300.herokuapp.com/en/articles. autocomplete box appears with no choices!
if nothing comes up in few days i think i'll try to write autocomplete without a gem.

Answer (score 0):

Did 2 things:
reroute routes (first in, fist out )

> get 'articles/autocomplete_article_title'
>   get "news/index" , as:'news'
>    resources :users
>   resources :news
>   resources :articles

and 2) reroute permissions in controller

```
 skip_before_filter :authorize, except: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```