# Jquery UI autocomplete and Rails 4 and Ransack. Not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Im stuck with this. I'm trying to make a search bar (in the header) to work with Jquery-UI autocomplete but I can't get it running.

*I installed the  gem 'rails4-autocomplete' and did bundle. 
I downloaded a custom version of Jquery UI with the autocomplete and added it to application.js as a require // ....*

**My code looks like this. It should be really simple to make it work:**

Note: I have nested Photos into Users. I want autocomplete to show the titles of the photos in the search bar. The thing is I'm using Ransack so I don't know how to make it work.

**UPDATED**
**Users Controller**

```
 class PhotosController < ApplicationController
 autocomplete :photo, :title
```

**UPDATED**
**My view (where the Search is)**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js',
  'autocomplete-rails.js' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css' %>

          <%= search_form_for @spot_search, url: search_path do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :title_cont, "data-autocomplete" => autocomplete_photo_title_photos_path, :size => 15, :placeholder => "¿Qué vas a decorar hoy?", class: "searchinput" %>
```

**UPDATED**
**Routes**

```
  #Autocomplete
resources :photos do
get :autocomplete_photo_title, :on => :collection
end
```

I don't know how to get this running and I'm making a mess with the gem / no gem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No...Can't understand it.

Comment: check if the answer in this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108197/using-autocomplete-in-app-with-ransack

Comment: what is error,, can you update server log

Comment: In JS console: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function autocomplete-rails.js?body=1:17